# How to add a column to a table using combined columns from the same table?

Tags: postgresql

I needed basic help on how to combine columns into one new column in the same table. I have done the below as a SELECT command and it works fine. I just don't know how to add it to the table permanently so that it becomes part of the table.

```
SELECT *, concat(z41, z42, z43, z44) AS option_3,
concat(z411, z412, z413, z421, z422, z423, z431, z432, z433, z434, z444,z443, z442, z441) AS option_4,
concat(z4211, z4212, z4213, z4214, z4215, z4311, z4312, z4313, z4314, z4431, z4432, z4433, z4434, z4421, z4422, z4423, z4424, z4425, z4426) AS option_5
FROM combined_full
```

Comment: I would suggest using a view and adding the expression to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, you are probably better off using a view. But if you *really* need this computed data in column then you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE combined_full ADD COLUMN option_3 varchar,
                          ADD COLUMN option_4 varchar,
                          ADD COLUMN option_5 varchar;

UPDATE combined_full
SET option_3 = concat(z41, z42, z43, z44),
    option_4 = concat(z411, z412, z413, z421, z422, z423, z431, z432, z433, z434, z444,z443, z442, z441),
    option_5 = concat(z4211, z4212, z4213, z4214, z4215, z4311, z4312, z4313, z4314, z4431, z4432, z4433, z4434, z4421, z4422, z4423, z4424, z4425, z4426);
```

When adding new rows to the table, you should either also enter values for these three new columns, or create an insert trigger so that the values are automatically calculated as you do above.

Comment: PERFECT!.. Thanks Patrick much appreciated, this was really annoying me.

Comment: @Ary: note that you **will** need a trigger to keep those values up-to-date.

Comment: I will also keep that in mind.. generally speaking the data I have currently does not update. Much appreciated for future use.

Answer (score 0):

"*so that it becomes part of the table*" - you can't. Unfortunately Postgres (as of 9.6) has no (persisted) computed columns.

If the expression is not very expensive to calculate and you don't need an index on it, I would suggest to create a view that contains the expression.

Given the example in your question, this should be good enough in your case as concatenating values isn't really that expensive.

If you really think you need to persist the calculation of the expression because e.g. you want to create an index on that or you constantly use that expression in a `where` clause, you will need to add a regular column to the table and a trigger that updates the expression when a row is inserted or updated.

Comment: The data in the columns are words, where there are gaps e.g. z41 is empty, z42 is empy, z43 is empy, z44 has 'Never been'. Could you combine them so that it becomes one column that only says 'Never been'? I dont knw if this helps..

Comment: @Ary: that is a totally different question. But `concat()` will do that